# Updating large MySQL table with values from another large table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, query-optimization

I have a table with around 2 million rows (450Mb) and I need to populate data into a single column via a check on another table with exactly the same structure and about 1.2 millio0n rows. I cannot find a way to do this that doesn't crash or timeout. The situation is as follows.

There are around 11000 distinct names in a table of nearly 2 million records. I need to get the code associated with each distinct name in Table A and then insert that code into all rows in Table B that have that name. It sounds easy but nothing works since it is having to search 2 million rows each time to find the right rows.

I've tried simple update queries - no luck. I've tried SSH access, no luck, and with batching even a sing1e query fails. I've resorted to trying to just go one row at a time from Table B and look for the code in Table A via the following and then updating Table B but still barely doing 2000 rows at a time.

```
    global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT t2.ID, t1.code FROM my_records AS t1 INNER JOIN my_records_new AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name WHERE t2.code = '' LIMIT 20000;";
$resArr = array(); 
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
foreach ($rows as $obj) { 
    $tid = $obj->ID; 
    $tcode = $obj->code; 
    $resArr[$tid]['tid'] = $tid;
    $resArr[$tid]['tcode'] = $tcode;
} 
foreach($resArr as $res) { 
    $tid = $res['tid']; 
    $tcode = $res['tcode']; 
    $wpdb->update( 
        'my_records_new', 
        array(  
            'code' => $tcode,
        ), 
        array( 'ID' => $tid ), 
        array( 
            '%s', 
        ), 
        array( '%d' ) 
    );
}
```

I don't see this is overly complex so I'm sure there must be a way to efficiently do this without having to run a file 1000s of times doing a few hundred rows at a time.

Any expert advise appreciated.

A query such as "update my_records_new set code='sdfsdf' where name='abc'" times out even as a single query let alone 11000.

Trying to add Indexes to the table times out as well. Continuing to run PHP page that adds about 800 updates at a time.

Comment: What does the execution plan of that query tell you about the performance? How is this problem related to PHP?

Comment: I've no idea Nico - the sql query is about the 5th attempt to find a way to get this done. Doesn't work with simple update queries based on the unique codes found. This method grabs a batch of codes and the ID for the update and puts into an array which is then used to run through the updates to the new table. Works slower than snail pace. PHP is included as I have no idea if there's some file that can be written to do this. Thanks

Comment: If there is no PHP code written yet, remove the tag. Also, share the execution plan of the slow running query

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the tables? I'm guessing that an index on both tables on the name column should help.

Comment: aynber - primary index for both tables is the ID but they are different for each table. we're using the ID on the new table to try to speed up the process but generally doesn't. There are about 11000 distinct names across 2 million rows so the names are duplicated many times within the data. A simple query like update code='sdfsdfsdfs' where name='abc' still times out which is why we are resorting to other ideas.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: A primary index is for keeping things in order and unique. But a regular index on a heavily compared column, such as the one you're using for your join condition, can speed up a query immensely.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to aynber for the constructive response to this.

Whilst I didn't understand anything on the linked page, I managed to have a guess at indexing columns on the new table and, whilst the phpmyadmin indexing request timed out and seemed to fail, re-running the PHP script written to update the rows is now running much, much faster and I'll be able to batch update the table fairly quickly.

Comment: Yeah, when a query, like your reindexing query, takes longer than a web app the query completes even though the web app times out. phpmyadmin is a web app.